# How to remove the parent id effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the specific effect added by the parent id attribute to be removed.

```
    <div id="js-item-notifymebtn-$item.itemid" style="display:none;">
        <div id="notifyComment"> This item is out of Stock 
        </div>
        <div class="btnclass addToCartBtn">
             <a class="btn-notify">
             <span>#springMessage('vm.wishlist.notifyme.button')</span>
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here the message I added "This item is out of Stock" is coming as button. Can anyone help me out how to make this as normal text.

I added the javaScript code like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#notifyComment").removeAttr("id");
    });
</script>
```

to remove the attribute id onload but not getting the required result.

Comment: show us a problem in fiddle. that should work. here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y9etS/

Comment: You should use a class then remove it with `$.removeClass('.name_of_the_class')`

Comment: But the id can't be changed in my case, since it is being used in many other places. And the button effect is getting added by the id (id="js-item-notifymebtn-$item.itemid")

Comment: An id should be unique within a same page. Are you using this id more than one time ?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question, your `div notifyComment` is displayed as a button? That is caused by the css on `#notifyComment`? If so, can you show the CSS?

Comment: Its not added by any CSS, its getting added by the id="js-item-notifymebtn-$item.itemid". I have defined an id="notifyComment" for my sake to select that div and remove the attribute id completely, so that parent id effect can be removed, but its not happening.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#notifyComment").parent().removeAttr("id");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9etS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

But the id can't be changed in my case, since it is being used in many other places. And the button effect is getting added by the id (id="js-item-notifymebtn-$item.itemid")

You must decide whether you want to solve your problem. If you create an omlette, you will have to break a few eggs. Make your effect dependent on a class instead of an id, fix your dependencies and then use something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#notifyComment").removeClass("myClass");
});
```

Comment: Hi here the problem is not with changing the id="notifyComment" to class="notifyComment". But I cant change id="js-item-notifymebtn-$item.itemid" to class="js-item-notifymebtn-$item.itemid". Basically the button effect is getting added by id="js-item-notifymebtn-$item.itemid".

Comment: I have edited my answer, my code was rubbish, sorry for that. You need to remove the class (myClass for instance) when you need to get rid of the effect and modify the dependency to depend on your classname instead of id. Note, that the id is present, so it might be the case that other dependencies are not damaged.